# Filtering mongodb data

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have the following model:

Base class:

```
public abstract class Identifiable{
    private ObjectId id;
    private string name;

    protected Identifiable(){
        id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId();
    }

    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id{
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    [BsonRequired]
    public string Name{
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
}
```

The name is unique.
A channel class

```
 public class Channel : Identifiable{
    private DateTime creationDate;

    private string url;
    private DailyPrograming dailyPrograming;

    public DailyPrograming DailyPrograming{
        get { return dailyPrograming; }
        set { dailyPrograming = value; }
    }

    public DateTime CreationDate{
        get { return creationDate; }
        set { creationDate = value; }
    }

    public string Url{
        get { return url; }
        set { url = value; }
    }
}
```

Daily programs. The name property is the date stored as ddMMyyyy:

```
public class DailyPrograming : Identifiable{
    public DailyPrograming(){
        DailyPrograms = new List<Program>(30);
    }

    public IList<Program> DailyPrograms { get; set; }
}
```

The programs:

```
public class Program : Identifiable{
    private DateTime programDate;
    private string category;
    private string description;

    public DateTime ProgramDate{
        get { return programDate; }
        set { programDate = value; }
    }

    public string Category{
        get { return category; }
        set { category = value; }
    }

    public string Description{
        get { return description; }
        set { description = value; }
    }
}
```

Now, I want to filter the program of certain channel for specific date using:

```
public DailyPrograming GetProgramsForDate(string channelId, string prgDate){
        ObjectId id = new ObjectId(channelId);
        IMongoQuery query = Query.And(Query<Channel>.EQ(c => c.Id, id), 
            Query<DailyPrograming>.EQ(dp => dp.Name, prgDate));
        var result = Database.GetCollection<DailyPrograming>(CollectionName).Find(query).FirstOrDefault();
        return result;
    }
```

But it never returns the existing data. How to retrieve the programings of a channel for a date?
     -

Comment: A `Query<Channel>` when working on the `DailyPrograming` collection makes no sense.

Comment: post some sample documents if its possible

Comment: @Disposer Sure:
http://jsfiddle.net/oscar_a/4zdotf7L/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your sample I used `id = "54c00c65c215161c7ce2a77c"` and `prgDate = "2212015"`

then I changed the query to this:

```
var collection = database.GetCollection<Channel>("test6");
var id = new ObjectId("54c00c65c215161c7ce2a77c");
var query = Query.And(Query<Channel>.EQ(c => c.Id, id), Query<Channel>.EQ(c => c.DailyPrograming.Name, "2212015"));
var result = collection.Find(query).FirstOrDefault();
```

this query works fine

Some point:

> Your collection type is `Chanel` not `DailyPrograming`
>   When your collection is  Chanel you have to use `Query<Channel>` and query  nested `DailyPrograming` via `Query<Channel>.EQ(c => c.DailyPrograming.Name, "2212015")`

Comment: Thanks. That was one of my firsts approach out of many, but unfortunately, it returns null when tested with known existing values in ddbb.

Comment: It works, thanks for your help! I'm still trying not to think as in a relational world.

Answer (score 17):

```
var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
var filt = builder.Eq("Price", "9.20")
         & builder.Eq("ProductName", "WH-208");
var list = await collection.Find(filt).ToListAsync();
```

We can use `&` instead of `$and`. See [this post](http://www.fourthbottle.com/2015/07/retrieve-selected-documents-from.html), for another example.